# Долгое нажатие на кнопку Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть UI Button, которая выполняет при нажатии на нее скрипт:

`ball.transform.position = new Vector3(ball.transform.position.x, ball.transform.position.y + 1, ball.transform.position.z);`

То есть поднимает мяч по оси y на 1 вверх.

Вопрос, как можно сделать долгое нажатие на кнопку, чтобы, держа палец на ней, мяч поднимался до определенной высоты по y, допустим до 10?

Comment: Если в лоб решать, заведите переменную типа `Vector3` у мяча, пусть он например в `FixedUpdate()` проверяет этот вектор на `.zero`, и если он не `zero`, то прибавляет этот вектор к своей позиции. А в кнопке на MouseDown записывайте в этот вектор некое значение, а по MouseUp `Vector3.zero`. А в целом - почитайте [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567).

Comment: вопрос несколько пересекается с вопросом:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1299710/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-buttonui-%d0%b2-unity-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b/1299753#1299753 но я не уверен имеет ли смысл ставить дубликат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым очевидным вариантом является предложенная в комментариях комбинация методов OnMouseDown() и OnMouseUp(), однако вы также можете использовать свою кнопку, которая будет содержать коллайдер и скрипт с методом OnMouseDrug(), где можно также отслеживать позицию касания через Input.GetTouch(0).position и таким образом даже регулировать скорость движения (что-то вроде джойстика).